# Como utilizar um método sem ter que importa-lo diretamente no arquivo que o invoca?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Em um de meus arquivos tenho o seguinte conteúdo:

```
function env(param, defaultValue) {
  return process.env[param] || defaultValue;
}

module.exports = {
  title: env('TITLE', 'valor padrao'),
  url: env('URL', 'http://localhost'),
  port: env('PORT', 80),
  asset_url: env('ASSET_URL', null),
  time_zone: 'America/Sao_Paulo'
}
```

Como poderia separar o trecho:

```
// arquivo: config/app.js
module.exports = {
  title: env('TITLE', 'valor padrao'),
  url: env('URL', 'http://localhost'),
  port: env('PORT', 80),
  asset_url: env('ASSET_URL', null),
  time_zone: 'America/Sao_Paulo'
}
```

Em um arquivo a parte, e ainda sim conseguir utilizar o `env` sem ter que importa-lo no arquivo de configuração apresentado acima?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar uma solução para o problema apresentando. A estrutura ficou mais ou menos assim:

Criei o arquivo de configurações em `/config/app.js`:

```
/** 
 * Centraliza as configurações essenciais do aplicativo.
 * @module configuration/app
*/

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Título da aplicação
   * @type {string}
   */
  name: env('APP_NAME', 'valor padrao'),

  /**
   * Ambiente de aplicação
   * @type {string}
   */
  env: env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

  /**
   * Gerencia o modo debug da aplicação
   * @type {boolean}
   */
  debug: env('APP_DEBUG', false),

  /**
   * URL de acesso a aplicação
   * @type {string}
   */
  url: env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

  /**
   * URL dos asset, arquivos estáticos
   * @type {string|null}
   */
  asset_url: env('ASSET_URL', null),

  /**
   * Porta onde o serviço web estará ouvindo
   * @type {number}
   */
  port: env('PORT', 80),

  /**
   * Zona de fuso horário do aplicativo, formato de data/hora
   * @type {string}
   */
  timezone: 'America/Sao_Paulo'
}
```

Criei um "Helper" em `/start/environmentSettings.js`:

```
require('dotenv/config');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

global.env = function env(param, defaultValue) {
  return process.env[param.toUpperCase()] || defaultValue;
}

const rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'config');

function config(param) {
  const [file, key] = param.split('.');  

  const pathFile = path.join(rootPath, file + '.js');

  if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
    const config = require(pathFile);
    return config[key];
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

No helper acima estou basicamente criando uma variável global `env` e exportando o método `config`, o qual utilizamos para acessar as configurações.

Por fim podemos testar assim:

```
const config = require('./environmentSettings');

console.log(config('app.title'));
```